# Can I convert a disc loaded with Win 7 Ult from GPT to MBR without data corruption or loss?

Tags: windows-7

Can I convert a disc loaded with Win 7 Ult from GPT to MBR without data corruption or loss?
Is there a recommended method?

Comment: Can it be done, it can be done, but it is extremely difficult to do so correctly and I would not advise anyone who didn't already how do it, to actually attempt to do it.  Why do you want to convert to MBR?

Comment: [Converting from GPT to MBR](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html)

Comment: Not if the hard drive is greater than 2TB, and contains the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Converting GPT to MBR manually usually involves wiping out the disk.
See for example the methods described in the article
[How to Convert GPT Disk to MBR Disk](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26203-convert-gpt-disk-mbr-disk.html).

Nevertheless, some free products claim to do it for you with no data loss:

- [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) with [tutorial](https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/Convert-GPT-disk-to-MBR-disk.html)
- [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.disk-partition.com/download.html)
  with [tutorial](http://www.disk-partition.com/help/convert-gpt-mbr-disk.html)
- [EaseUS Partition Master Free](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm)
  with [tutorial](http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/GPT-disk-partition-manager/convert-gpt-disk-to-mbr-disk.htm)
- [Easy Recovery Essentials](https://neosmart.net/EasyRE/)
  with [tutorial](https://neosmart.net/wiki/convert-gpt-to-mbr/)

However, I repeat that when doing this conversion you have a reasonable
chance of destroying your disk and data.

Comment: harrymc: Thanks for the assist. I wish the news was better, but I appreciate input.